# Помогите исправить синтаксическую ошибку

Tags: php, база-данных, phpmyadmin, form

Ошибка :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\Users\Filip\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\daget.ua\settings.php on line 23

---

Код :

```
    <?php 

      if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
      mysqli_query($connection_mysqli , 
     "UPDATE  users 
      SET     $_SESSION['logged_user']->avatar = '".$_POST['f']."' //23
      WHERE   id = '".$_SESSION['id']."' " );
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: приведите содержимое 23 строки файла C:\Users\Filip\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\daget.ua\settings.php

Comment: `SET     $_SESSION['logged_user']->avatar = '".$_POST['f']."'` переменная = переменная

Comment: @СергейКоновалов привел коментом в коде

Comment: @DaemonHK а как тогда сделать замену?

Comment: @mbfilipp `SET     avatar = '".$_POST['f']."'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы навсегда избежать этих (и куда более серезных проблем), запрос надо исполнять так

```
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
    $stmt = $connection_mysqli->prepare("UPDATE  users SET avatar=? WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['f'], $_SESSION['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Поскольку мы не пытаемся запихнуть переменные прямо в запрос, то мы избегаем как ошибок синтсксиса PHP и SQL, так и SQL инъекций.